# What is wrong in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

Question:   Find the values of $p$ for which the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln (n)}{n^p}$ is convergent.

Note that $\ln(n) < n$ for all integers $n \geq 1$. That is, $ \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^p} <  \dfrac{n}{n^p} = \dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}}$ for all integers $n\geq 1$. Now, using the Comparison Test it follows that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln (n)}{n^p}$ is convergent if the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}}$ is convergent. The later, by the p-series test, converges if $p-1 > 1$. Therefore $p > 2$.

**My question is why this approach is not giving me the optimal answer p>1.**

Comment: You proved that $p \gt 2$ is sufficient for convergence, but not that it's necessary.

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is actually bounded above by any positive power of $x$ for big enough $x$.

Comment: ^ and it turns out $p>2$ is not a necessary condition. The series actually converges even for $p>1$, because $\log x$ grows much slower than any positive power of $x$.

Comment: The part highlighted in the latest edit is answered in my first comment. In more detail: "*it follows that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln (n)}{n^p}$ is convergent $\color{red}{\text{if}}$ the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}}$ is convergent*" $\;-\;$ You proved the "***if***", but what was needed is an "*if* ***and only if***" condition, instead.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "What is wrong in this proof?" says nothing about the subject of the proof. Look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect to get the optimal answer? You used the inequality $\ln n < n$ which is a very loose inequality when $n$ is big. The inequality $\ln n <n^{1/2}$ is also true for all $n\ge 1$ and is tighter, so it will give you a better bound for $p$.

In general, when you use an inequality to bound a function you lose some precision in exchange of working with a function that is easier to manipulate, so it's completely normal not to get the optimal behavior unless the bound is, in some sense, tight.